# Django Forms: How to validate if two fields are the same, e.g. email or password?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

I have scoured related SO posts and Django docs, can't quite get it to work. My form:

```
from django import forms

class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    (...)
    email              = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)
    email_conf         = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)

    def clean(self):
        form_data = self.cleaned_data

        if form_data['email'] != form_data['email_conf']:
            self._errors['email_conf'] = 'Emails do not match.'   # attempt A
            self.add_error('email', 'Emails do not match.')       # attempt B
            raise forms.ValidationError('Emails do not match.')   # attempt C
        return form_data
```

If the emails do NOT match, I'd like for Django to use my message string in the same manner as its other validations -- as a `<li>` element of `<ul class='errorlist'>` under the 'email_conf' field.

From the three attempts above, the only one that actually seems to do something is #A, but the message is inserted into the `{{ form.email_conf.errors }}` template as a plain string (not as a list item).

The other two attempts do not do anything, and in ALL cases if either field is empty, Django now throws `KeyError`.

Would love to know what's the correct way to achieve the result I'm after. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you should use error_class method of the form, like in example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). Also you should delete 'email_conf' element from cleaned_data dict. It's also very important to make sure all the keys do present in cleaned data (that these keys validated on previous steps of validation).

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(SignUpForm, self).clean()
    email = cleaned_data.get('email')
    email_conf = cleaned_data.get('email_conf')

    if email and email_conf and email != email_conf:
        self._errors['email_conf'] = self.error_class(['Emails do not match.'])
        del self.cleaned_data['email_conf']
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thank you. You're missing `.get` in `email_conf = cleaned_data('email_conf')` -- won't let me do edits less than 6 chars -- but otherwise works great. Much appreciated!

Comment: The link above is broken, but the information can be found here. You can change the Django version on the bottom right of the screen. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other